# Show button only on first tablerow of specific class

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically generated table that shows different courses. This table is generated by PHP, and gives every row a button. However, for a multi-day course I only want one button, instead of three buttons.

[image]

I want to solve this through CSS because it is not possible to adjust in PHP (long story).

The HTML (folded) of the table is:

```
<table class="events-table">
<tbody>
<tr class="cursus"><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></tr>
<tr class"meerdaagsecursus_sub2"><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></tr>
<tr class"meerdaagsecursus_sub2"><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></tr>
<tr class"meerdaagsecursus_sub2"><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></tr>
<tr class="cursus"><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the following in CSS attempt, but I can't figure it out:

```
.meerdaagsecursus_sub2:nth-child(1n+2) .ButtonInschrijven {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know it's a multi day course? Surely this would be best done in your php to add a `rowspan` (and not add the other buttons) when you know the course is over multiple days

Otherwise if you are determined to do it with css you can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`)

```css
.meerdaagsecursus_sub2+.meerdaagsecursus_sub2 .ButtonInschrijven {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="events-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="cursus">
      <td><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="meerdaagsecursus_sub2">
      <td><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="meerdaagsecursus_sub2">
      <td><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven hidden</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="meerdaagsecursus_sub2">
      <td><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven hidden</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cursus">
      <td><a class="ButtonInschrijven" href="http://">Inschrijven</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column in your courses table in the database named multiday and set its value for 1 if that course is a multi-day course, and when you create table dynamically, create a variable whose value is set to 0. Add a custom class name to the button where multi-day course value = 1 and change the variable to 1. while adding the custom class apply this if statement to check for the value of that variable, if its value has changed to 1 do not add that class to other buttons.

======give that class style="display:block"==========

i hope that will solve your problem